# How do I remove the status bar from a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, applepay

I am developing an app that will include Apple Pay. When I present a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController it shows the status bar on top of the screen, which I would like to keep hidden since it does not appear anywhere else in the app.

I tried overriding the view controller's behavior through subclassing:

```
@interface MyPaymentAuthorizationViewController : PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController

@end

@implementation MyPaymentAuthorizationViewController

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Though this results in a console message saying "PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController does not support subclassing." and the app crashing. Is it possible to present the view controller without the status bar appearing?